# How to calculate $\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{1 - \sin^2 \theta}\;\mathrm d\theta$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

How to calculate:

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{1 - \sin^2 \theta}\;\mathrm d\theta $$

Comment: You could use the Pythagorean identity to simplify your integrand...

Comment: The identity $1 - \sin^2{\theta} = \cos^2{\theta}$ should prove useful =)

Comment: Additionally, you could reduce it to the integral $$2\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}\mathrm d\theta$$

Comment: More elaborate hint: don't *blindly* use the Pythagorean identity. Plot the integrand and then apply the identity accordingly.

Comment: @J.M.: Is the potential pitfall blindly using the trig identity, or thinking that $\sqrt{x^2}=x$ rather than $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$?

Comment: @Isaac: Apparently I was not thinking straight writing that last comment; so yes, the second one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Hint*: note that $$\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}=\sqrt{\cos^2\theta}=|\cos\theta|.$$

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that $\cos^{2}\theta = 1-\sin^{2}\theta$ and the fact that integral of $\cos\theta$ is $\sin\theta$. Also $\sqrt{1-\sin^{2}\theta} = |\cos{\theta}|$. And note that $\cos\theta$ is positive in the first and the fourth quadrant.

Comment: The integral of $\cos{\theta}$ is $\sin{\theta}$ not $-\sin{\theta}$ :)

Comment: @Osama: Sorry. I have rectified it now. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

Use Wolfram Alpha!
Plug in "integrate sqrt(1-sin^2(x))". Then press "show steps". You can enter the bounds by hand...

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sqrt%281-sin%5E2%28x%29%29

Comment: Great tool, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{1 - \sin^2 \theta} d\theta &= \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{\cos^2 \theta} d\theta \\ &= \int_0^{2\pi} | \cos \theta | d\theta
\\ &= 4 \int_0^{\frac{pi}{4}} \cos \theta d\theta
\\ &= 4
\end{align}